# MongoDB Monitoring Service in your rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I look https://mms.10gen.com/ But i dont get it how to use your app to it. I mean how to connect your mongodb database link to MongoDB Monitoring Service? I am using Ruby on Rails and Mongodb in my project.

Comment: You install the mms agent on your mongodb servers and data about them should start to show up on mms.10gen.com . That's all there is to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface tells you step by step how to do it, but here is a tutorial link: http://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html .

Basically to explain it further, it does not run within your application; it is not connected to your application in anyway. Imagine it as a separate program sitting on your DB server(s) transmitting data to MMS. This does mean of course that you will need to configure your firewall (or use localhost resolution for it like I do) to allow the program out bound traffic access to the MMS site.

A more technical explanation is that it is a Python agent that runs as a deamon on your machine. It will automatically, once placed on a server, detect the cluster (unless your single server then it will just get the one server) and add it to the site. It may take a while (5 mins or so) for data to show up.

Comment: I am able to implement mms . here it shows status successfully. also it shows all my dbs name in DB stats but fails in showing statistics. What may be the problem

Comment: Do you mean the hardware, is munin installed? http://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html#hardware-monitoring-with-munin-node

Comment: munin part is done..  I did edit the settings.py file in my agent installation, so that the useSslForAllConnections value is True
Now when i run python agent.py  error comes ConnectionFailure: SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.

Comment: Yea you can only use SSL if MongoDB is setup to handle SSL connections, you are probably looking to actually make that value false.

Comment: i couldnot get statistics of my database dbstats(where i have all database)

Comment: Ah! yea it did take some time for me, I reckoned 5 mins but maybe it was longer